# How to force SQ in Informatica to use query from file in Unix path

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a mapping with one port in SQ transformation with char data type. Now I want the SQ to use query(obviously will return one column) that I will place in a unix path. Whenever I change the query in unix, mapping will generate different data set depending upon the query. 
Is there any way out to do that with SQ or even with others transformation? 
I don't want to parameterise the query and to use the parameter in SQ. This will possibly lead to size constraint of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand the aversion to parameter file - how big can a query that returns 1 column be? If you're in doubt then see the following very similar thread where nico has provided good indication on the string parameter limits i.e. over 32000 characters. https://network.informatica.com/thread/20140

You could also expand your allocation by using SELECT $$Selection FROM $$Sources WHERE $$Conditions

Comment: Query is returning one column but it includes the concatenated value of all of the columns in the table.

Comment: From where I'm sitting that poses more of a problem for the size of the outgoing column than the query definition. Have you tried parameterising the query first and then picked up problems or are you assuming you'll see problems further down the line? How many columns do your tables have? Is it the concatenation functions bloating your query that you're worried about? You realise you could also do something like SELECT $$Selection1 $$Selection2 $$Selection3 FROM $$Sources WHERE $$Condition

Answer (score 1):

Creating a mapping that runs any given query is in general a bad idea. PowerCenter is NOT a SQL Statement Execution Tool.

To do that, you don't need PowerCenter. You will even come across many issues. Create some simple jar or use any scripting language.

PowerCenter is a tool to do the data processing. Sources should reflect the underlying data structures. Source Qualifier should handle data from the underlying tables. You cannot create one that reflect structure of any given table.

Anyway: another solution is to try to keep your statements in a DB and use a parametrized SP to execute the desired one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL transformation in script mode for this purpose. Just pass the SQL filename with path to the SQL transformation.

Comment: As much I know in script mode integration service ignores the output of select statements in the SQL scripts. So I will not get the output in SQL transformation out port to propagate to the target.